# In Eclipse, can you define preprocessor variables for all projects in a workspace?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a Eclipse workspace with several C projects: Project1, Project2, Project3, ... Project2, Project3, etc. all include a header from Project1. This header is heavy on preprocessor directives, such as:

```
#ifdef OPTION1
  typedef MY_INT int;
#endif
```

To make Eclipse find `MY_INT` in the code in Project2, Project3, I currently have to  add the preprocessor definition `OPTION1` for each project separately.

Is there a way to define `OPTION1` globally, just once, for all the projects in the workspace.

Comment: I doubt there is such an option (I can't find it). But I think it's better not to have it, because once you set it and forget, you will bash your head against the wall trying figure out how to get rid of these mysterious symbols defined nowhere.

Comment: Defining it in your header from Project1, which you include in all your projects?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

A bit longer: workspace may consist of many projects with completely different natures. Not all of them have preprocessor settings at all.